# What are the 'hiq' and 'siq' fields in dstat cpu output

Tags: metrics

dstat CPU metrics have two fields named `hiq` and `siq`. What do these fields represent? Are they some sort of hardware interrupts and software interrupts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are from `/proc/stat` (http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm):

```
hiq - irq: servicing interrupts
siq - softirq: servicing softirqs
```